# Index both an element and its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a jquery tab like set-up, however the `tabs` contain other elements that are being indexed at -1 rather then the index of their parent `DIV`, how could I index the nested elements accordingly or how would I use `event.stopPropagation();` to invalidate, actions caused by nested elements?

[Here Is a js fiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/n8zxuqwc/7/)

```
$.fn.tabSample = function () {
$(this).each(function (idx, el) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on('click','.tabs .tab', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var index = $this.find(".tabs .tab").index(event.target);
        $this.find(".contents div").removeClass('active');
        $this.find(".tabs .tab").removeClass('active');
        var item = $this.find(".contents div:eq(" + index + ")").addClass('active');
        var item2 = $this.find(".tabs .tab:eq(" + index + ")").addClass('active');

        console.log(item, item2, event.target, index);
    });
});
};

$('html').click(function () {
//Hide the menus if visible
   $(".active").removeClass('active');
   var $this = $(this);
   var index2 = $this.find(".tab button").index(event.target);
   console.log(index2);
});


$(".tab-control").tabSample();
```

Comment: If you're using jquery 1.9 you should be using `on` instead of `delegate`.

Comment: Yes you are correct I have updated the code accordingly